# Error on git pull error : cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied

Tags: windows, git, jenkins, cmd, permission-denied

I'm looking for help !!

I am getting the following error message when trying to complete a git pull;

C:\Jenkins\Repo> git pull error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied

The machine in question is Windows Server 2008 r2 OS and were using ssh to handle the authentication.

**We have tried the following;**
Checked that the current user the correct read/write on the FETCH_HEAD file, which it does, also checking that the user has the correct permissions set on the repo root.

I have tried to load my private key (which I know 100% works and has permissions to the repo in question) and still the same issue... so from little I know regarding git I think this is more of a Windows issue

and lots of Google !

Any more ideas on what to do/check would be a great help !

Comment: Do you *have* a `FETCH_HEAD` file?  Can you delete it?  (Running `fetch` will recreate it.)  It's possible that another program has it open and `git` cannot recreate it.

Answer (score 23):

This happened to me after I upgraded to Windows 10. While my user is an administrator and Administrators had full access to the root repo folder, my user was not explicitly listed. I've added my user with Full Control and it solved the problem for me (had the same issue with Outlook refusing to read the PST file until I did the same thing).

So, for me, the solution is:

- Right click on the folder, select properties
- Security
- Edit
- Add
- Type in my user name
- Check Full Control under Allow
- OK, OK

Answer (score 8):

On Windows 10 this is what worked for me:

```
1. go to the repo folder 
2. right click on the .git folder and choose the last option - properties
3. on the general tab uncheck hidden checkbox if checked
4. hit apply and then ok
```

now go try git fetch or git pull and it should work.

Comment: Oh damn!
I spent almost two days to check complex solutions (authentication changes, command line operations, etc.) about this issue whereas this **really simple** manipulation seems to solve it!

Comment: I worked in my Downloads folder and figured I had to clear the Read-only attribute to be able to run git pull. A quick search online [showed](https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-folder-keeps-reverting-to-read-only-on-windows-10/) that Windows Virus & threat protection has a controlled folder access feature that keeps the folder as read-only. This is not even available for configuring when another antivirus such as a corporate-controlled one takes over. It seems the entire Downloads folder is controlled against writes by anything but the browsers.

Answer (score 3):

This is fairly a common problem. I've come across it many times and almost all of the times, the issue is with the right **permissions** to the repo/directory `.git/`  and the right SSH keys to access the git repository.

You probably need to make the user, the owner of the repository `chown` (Give full access to the user) or, clone the repository to a different directory.

You can set the write permission with the following command
go to your folder `chown -R youruser:yourgroup .git/`

Also try to un-hide the .git folder.

Comment: Hey Anantha Raju C, thank you for getting back to me.

This is on a Windows System so I have tried the Windows version of `chown -R` which is `takeown /R /D Y /F *` and that didnt take any effect.

Comment: @craig Rickett this may help you to take ownership of the repo http://serverfault.com/a/27339/308384

Answer (score 2):

In my case, this happend because I hide the `.git` folder by hand(usually it will be hide automatically) but I forgot it.

I have tried edit security but no effect. So I just show the `.git` folder and solve the problem.

May this can be help for someone

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me because after updating windows.
Kindly try these steps:

1. Right click on folder -> properties
2. Under general there are two checkbox hidden and read only -> uncheck the hidden check box and click on apply
3. Under security -> edit -> add user -> apply
4. give full access to your user

This will work for you

Answer (score 0):

just remove the folder,and clone again.

Comment: This is a little unclear ... perhaps specify which folder the OP should delete before attempting to clone again?

Comment: Just remove the whole project fold,and clone again.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was open powershell / command prompt with Administrative rights inside the repository, and I was able to pull / fetch / merge and push.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can also be caused by the caches Jenkins keeps of it's Git operations. I had tried `chown`ing the files I thought were causing the problem, I also deleted the workspace completely.

After deleting `%ProgramData%\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspaces\MY-BUILD*` I still had the exact same error message.

In `%ProgramData%\Jenkins\.jenkins\caches` I deleted everything but you could probably just delete the `git-<HEX_ID>` and `git-<HEX_ID>@tmp` folders and retry the same checkout. This resolved the issue for me as Jenkins was forced to recreate the `.git` folder in both the workspace and the cache and the permissions were then correct.

Steps:

1. Delete the workspace folders of the troublesome job
2. Delete the Git caches
3. Retry the job